# What happens if I delete Vesta Panel in my server?

Tags: server, ftp, vesta

I have Linux(CENTOS 7) server in Vultr. I was working with Vesta Panel and now i want to delete it. But I really can't find what happens if I delete it. Folders, databases etc.

I need to just delete vesta panel and keep the wordpress websites. There are two ftp port, two user and password. One of I can see my other ".net core" projects one of is for vesta panel folders(wordpress folders).

I am really confused. How can i do it? How can I delete Vesta Panel? How can I see wordpress folders and other project folders with just one ftp port?

Answer (score 0):

If you delete vestacp, I'm afraid that your website may get problems. I have not did this, but I guess vestacp control dns, ftp accounts, mysql, php, etc...